# Is the Upside-Down "feature" of Karateka endemic to the Apple II?

Tags: apple-ii, karateka

[According to Jason Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnEWBtCnFs8), 1984 saw Broderbund's Customer Service answer the following error quite a lot. The question came up because allegedly Jordan Mechner and the company found it funny to increase the manufacturing costs for an easter egg:

> My screen is upside down! How do I fix that?!

[Here you can see *that* it works...](https://youtu.be/xNTvblHVzJw), and [here you can see an original 5.25 double-sided disk and its use of an original disk](https://youtu.be/4WNYrikbtcY)

Of course, the answer lay in the [shape of the [double sided] floppy disk and explained in the same talk:](https://youtu.be/FnEWBtCnFs8?&t=548) there is an index hole on them. Typically, a (double sided) floppy drive<sup>1</sup> had two readers for that hole, one left and one right. Often, B was empty. But for Karateka, the B-side had the same stuff on it, yet all the images were upside down, rendering the whole game upside down.

However, the game *also*, again, Jason Scott quoting Jordan Mechner, was totally re-coded to get it to other platforms, such as Atari 8-bit, C64, NES and others till 1990.

**Was the "feature" of the upside-down B-side exclusive to the Apple II edition?**

---

1 - Single-side only 5.25" drives exist, and for those "flippy" disks with two index holes allowed writing and reading to both sides. At least one version of Questprobe was distributed on such disks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You can't flip pc disks upside down and have them work, even 5 1/4 ones, since the drives are double sided already.

The c64 and atari version, as well as the others, were ports by others which didn't include the easter egg.

Comment: But as a feature it doesn't require a medium that can be flipped. And do you have any sources for your information?

Comment: double sided disks and readers exist in 8" and 5.25 inch. Only 3.5 inch are not double sided ever. For example, the Victor 9000 / ACT Sirius 1 was shipped with a drive that can read 1.2 MB, 5.25" Double Sided, Double Density drives, made in 1982.

Comment: For example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spiderman_Flippy_Disk.jpg) disk has two index holes (and no write notch) and holds the 1985 Questprobe Spiderman. By turning this disk "upside down" the other side can be read in a single-sided reader.

Comment: In a similar fashion: [International Karate for Atari on 5.25" disk](https://www.retrogames.co.uk/018658/Atari/International-Karate-by-System-3) had the C64 version on its flipside.

Comment: Karateka PC is not one of those double index hole disks. https://www.oldgames.sk/images/oldgames/action/Karateka/Covers/.thumbs/_gallery_karateka-dos-fdd5.jpg

This is proof the PC ver didn't have this.

Comment: The atari and c64 version could have done it, because their drives ignore the index sensor, but the guy who did the port (robert cook) didn't bother to do the easter egg.  Only the apple II original had the feature.